# What are the four black rubbery chocolate slab-like things included with my motherboard?

Tags: installation, motherboard

I just bought a [FoxConn H67S motherboard](http://www.foxconnchannel.com/ProductDetail.aspx?T=motherboard&U=en-us0000515) (mini ITX FF) and it came with 4 rubbery things that look like half a bar of chocolate. They have adhesive on the back with peel-off stickers. I'm not sure what to do with these -- anyone know?

[image: Picture of the thing]

Comment: Do they *smell* like chocolate?  Have you tasted one?  Don't, they're *rubber*.

Comment: Are you sure they didn't come with the case or something rather than the MB?

Comment: @dangph: That was my guess as well... but they were in the little plastic bag with my mobo. There is a 2% chance I subconsciously took it from the packaging for the case and transferred it to the mobo bag, but if that were true, I have other problems I'd worry about first.

Comment: Why the downvote, I wonder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are self-adhesive non-skid rubber feet.

They're usually found on small consumer-oriented, desk-bound devices.  They're frequently bundled separately so you can choose if they need to be applied.

There is no reason that they should have been in your motherboard box.  Stash'em away somewhere, maybe you'll be (un)lucky enough to buy something that *should* have included a set, but didn't.

Comment: Hmm, this was my guess as well; it was very surprising (pleasantly though).